# Type mismatch Expression type could not be evaluated. Correct the expression

Tags: azure-synapse

I am completely new to Dataflows. This is my very first attempt at creating one. Here is a snapshot of the data I am working with:

| Region Name | Location ID | Client Lot ID | Stall | Location Name | Vehicle Type | Vehicle ID | License Plate | Member ID | Date Start | Transaction ID | Parking Segment ID | New or Extended Parking Session | Payment Amount Total | Date Expire | Parking Amount Total | Paid Duration | Eligibility Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Springfield | 10007 | 10007 |  | 652 8th Avenue | Car | 32398094 | GW22DQZ | 22975507 | 2/1/2023 16:54 | 851821344 | 373089038 | Is_Not_Extension | 73.08 | 2/4/2023 18:46 | 73.08 | 80 | CUSTOM |
| Springfield | 10019 | 10019 |  | Sycamore Avenue | Car | 93477580 | ZE26IIN | 76168871 | 11/14/2023 1:21 | 376869951 | 536357227 | Is_Not_Extension | 69.97 | 11/15/2023 13:13 | 69.97 | 185 | CUSTOM |
| Springfield | 10003 | 10003 |  | 181st Street | Car | 37155431 | BG61HXC | 12859951 | 5/30/2023 2:20 | 835908431 | 878681088 | Is_Not_Extension | 38.33 | 6/6/2023 19:20 | 38.33 | 188 | CUSTOM |

The first thing I did was remove the Stall column. Then I changed the datatype from string to integer (I think it's correct):

[image]

```
toInteger({Payment Amount Total})
```

Then I tried to multiply the 'Payment Amount Total' column by 2 using this expression:

```
[Payment Amount Total] * 2
```

but it's giving me an error:

```
Type mismatch
Expression type could not be evaluated. Correct the expression.
```

[image]

Comment: What do you see in the Expression editor for the data type?

Comment: I might be misreading, but you've created a derived column, called DerivedColumn1, which contains a conversion of the Pay amount to an integer.  But instead of using that new column in your multiplication, you're using the original column?  shouldn't you just use the derived column in your calc? [derivedColumn1] * 2

Comment: No that's jus the name of the transformation step. You can call it anything you like it just has to be unique. Synapse gives it a default name and then you can change it if you like. I've left mine to their default name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i got the same error in my environment.

[image]

That is because when you give it inside square brackets it takes it as array type, and gives **Type mismatch** error.

So, alter it as below
`{vechicle vin}*2`

For your case it is `{Payment Amount Total}*2`

[image]

Output:

[image]